# CSS does not apply some parts

Tags: html, css

Just started with HTML: http://pastebin.com/ZQr99cnr, and am wondering why .main-part doesn't apply for bottom side. Also the only thing from .bottom-part that applies is text-align: center. Everything else seems to be ignored.

```css
body {
color: #330000;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #ffffcc;
margin-left: -450px;
family-font: Verdana;
width: 900px;
height: 420px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%; }
 
.jake-cofee-shop {
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
background-color: #ccaa66;
text-align:center; }
 
.left-part {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
margin-left:-1px;
background-color: #E8D882; }
 
.right-part {
float: right;
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
margin-right: -1px;
background-color: #f1e8b0; }
 
.main-part {
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #f1e8b0; }
 
h4 {
padding-left: 12px; }
 
h5 {
padding-left: 12px; }
 
li {
padding-left: 12px; }
 
.image-perfection {
float: right;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top: 75px; }
 
.bottom-part {
height: 60px;
background-color: #ccaa66
;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px; }
```

```html
 
<h1 class="jake-cofee-shop">Jake's Cofee Shop</h1>
 
<div class="main-part">
<div class="left-part">
<h4><a href="#">Home</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Menu</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Music</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Jobs</a></h4>
</div>
 
<div class="right-part">
<h5>Come in and experience...</h5>
<img class="image-perfection" width="250em" src="http://thumbs.xdesktopwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/White%20Coffe%20Cup%20With%20Beans-720x405.jpg"></img>
 
<ul>
<li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
<li>Freshly made sandwiches</li>
<li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
<li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
<li>Open mic nights</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
 
<h5 style="margin-bottom:-20px">23 Pine Road</h5>
<h5 style="margin-bottom:-20px">Nottingham, NG1 5YU</h5>
<h5>0115 9324567</h5>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="bottom-part">
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 0px">Copyright @2011 Jake's Coffee House</h5>
<a href="http:www.google.com">jake@jcoffee.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question. External links tend to expire, etc.

Comment: Put you code on jsfiddle for instance, you'll see that all style of .bottom-part is applied. Obviously don't see any problem you described. Still, remove the close tag </img> which is inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your .main-part contains floating divs only, and the floating divs don't force the height of the .main-part to clear them.

As a result, the .main-part div's height is only 2px, and the .bottom-part is sitting right after .main-part (2px below the .top-part) behind everything.

You could add

```
.main-part:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

to force the .main-part div's height to clear the floating divs.

Comment: I got the borders now, but the color is still not showing up.

Comment: @JanLovšin To me, if i add the css that I gave you, it shows well. See the [link](http://codepen.io/jpdupere/pen/YWVmWk) Or let me know what you expected to be different.

Comment: Oh ye it works with the original one... guess that is what :after means. But what about if I nest left, right and bottom part within main part?

Comment: I personally think it's a better design to keep the footer outside of the main area, but if you want to put the footer inside the .main-part div, you just have to add `clear:both;` to the .bottom-part css. This will ensure the .bottom-part will clear the floating divs.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't apply because `.bottom-part` is not a child of `.main-part`. You have to nest them if you want to inherit from main-part:

```
<h1 class="jake-cofee-shop">Jake's Cofee Shop</h1>

<div class="main-part">
<div class="left-part">
<h4><a href="#">Home</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Menu</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Music</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#">Jobs</a></h4>
</div>

<div class="right-part">
<h5>Come in and experience...</h5>
<img class="image-perfection" width="250em" src="http://thumbs.xdesktopwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/White%20Coffe%20Cup%20With%20Beans-720x405.jpg"></img>

<ul>
<li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
<li>Freshly made sandwiches</li>
<li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
<li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
<li>Open mic nights</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>

<h5 style="margin-bottom:-20px">23 Pine Road</h5>
<h5 style="margin-bottom:-20px">Nottingham, NG1 5YU</h5>
<h5>0115 9324567</h5>
</div>
<div class="bottom-part">
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 0px">Copyright @2011 Jake's Coffee House</h5>
<a href="http:www.google.com">jake@jcoffee.com</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ye my mistake didn't see. But anyway this also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what it should look like ? That was the first thing I've noticed.

Comment: I'm guessing your running it in browser. The Jake's coffe shop and the part with copyright should be orange and there should be black borders all around them. Middle is yellow. But .bottom-part doesn't like work.